# Where's the merge dialog when you need it?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge

I checked out some files to write some code. When I was finished I did a get latest before checking in.

There were conflicts when Getting Latest however, I did not get a merge dialog like I was used to at previous places of employment.

This time I only got a message in the output saying:

> Warning - Unable to refresh {file} because you have a pending edit.

Is there a setting I'm missing or something?